# The retrofit call not update viewmodel or viewmodel not update the view

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I try get a user from a rest api for do login in my android app for get this I have the next code

LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private   LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActivityLoginBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login);
        loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        binding.setLoginViewModel(loginViewModel);
        binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);

        loginViewModel.user.observe(this, new Observer<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.java

```
public class LoginViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private LoginRespository loginRespository = new LoginRespository();
    public MutableLiveData<User> user = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MutableLiveData<String> email = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> password = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public LoginViewModel() {}

    public void onLoginClicked() {
        user = loginRespository.doLogin(email.getValue(), password.getValue());
    }

}
```

LoginRepository.java

```
@Singleton
public class LoginRespository {
    private APIInterface apiInterface;

    public LoginRespository(){
        this.apiInterface = APIClient.getClient().create(APIInterface.class);
    }

    //private final APIInterface apiInterface;
    /*@Inject
    public LoginRespository(APIInterface apiInterface) {
        this.apiInterface = apiInterface;
    }*/

    public MutableLiveData<User> doLogin(String email, String password) {
        final MutableLiveData<User> data = new MutableLiveData<>();

        Call<User> call = apiInterface.doGetLogin(email, password, APIClient.X_API_KEY, APIClient.X_CLIENT_ID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                User user = response.body();
                Log.d("#####0", user.toString());
                if (user.code.equals(APIClient.Codes.OK)){
                    Log.d("#####1", user.toString());
                    data.setValue(user);
                    Log.d("#####2", data.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                call.cancel();
            }
        });

        return data;
    }
}
```

User.java

```
public class User{

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    public String code;
    @SerializedName("data")
    @Expose
    public List<Datum> data = null;
    @SerializedName("description")
    @Expose
    public String description;
    @SerializedName("datetime")
    @Expose
    public String datetime;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public User() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param description
     * @param data
     * @param code
     * @param datetime
     */
    public User(String code, List<Datum> data, String description, String datetime) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.data = data;
        this.description = description;
        this.datetime = datetime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "code='" + code + '\'' +
                ", data=" + data +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", datetime='" + datetime + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

In the view, I have two EditText for do login and work perfectly because I can pass email and password into LoginRepositori.doLogin and I get the response with a user, but when I want to get the update about the user data in the activity with loginViweMode.User.observe... I never get notifications.

Then how can do it, for that the loginViewModel.User.observe... in the activity be called.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing out on some connections between activity and view model. Since repository returns new live data object each time `user` will not be able to observe since it's value is replaced by the login call.

To solve this you can either pass the user livedata to repository and update its value from repository rather creating new object in every call

or you can use switchMap() transformation function to transform the result into `user` variable

Comment: I do not know if it is a good practice but in the end I chose to pass the parameter to the repository. The code is now the next public void doLogin(final MutableLiveData<User> data, String email, String password) {
        Call<User> call = apiInterface.doGetLogin(email, password, APIClient.X_API_KEY, APIClient.X_CLIENT_ID);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                data.setValue(response.body());
            }
....

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new `user` `LiveData` instance in call below (different to one you're actually observing in `LoginActivity`.

```
public void onLoginClicked() { 
    user = loginRespository.doLogin(email.getValue(), password.getValue());
}
```

Comment: But then how can pass the value from the repository? the call method is async and I cannot pass only the value because I do not have

Comment: You still need to manage async aspect of this....but not sure there's value specifically in using `LiveData` in your repository code for this....but if you are taking this approach take a look perhaps at using `Transformations.switchMap()` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations)

Comment: If you were using some kind of callback for example for when async was completed then you'd do something like `user.value = <result>`.

Comment: I am trying to like a https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#recommended_app_architecture maybe the code that I use has a concept error. Thanks for all.

Comment: Did you try using `switchMap()` ?

Comment: That link I included has nice example which I think is pretty close to what you have there